# XPathSelectElements returns null

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

Load function is already defined in xmlData class

```
public class XmlData
{
    public void Load(XElement xDoc)
    {
        var id = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ID");
        var listIds = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Lists//List/ListIDS/ListIDS");
    }
}
```

I'm just calling the Load function from my end.

```
            XmlData aXmlData = new XmlData();

            string input, stringXML = "";
            TextReader aTextReader = new StreamReader("D:\\test.xml");
            while ((input = aTextReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                stringXML += input;
            }
            XElement Content = XElement.Parse(stringXML);
            aXmlData.Load(Content);
```

in load function,im getting both id and and listIds as null.

My test.xml contains

```
<SEARCH>
  <ID>11242</ID>
  <Lists>
    <List CURRENT="true" AGGREGATEDCHANGED="false">
      <ListIDS>
        <ListID>100567</ListID>
        <ListID>100564</ListID>
        <ListID>100025</ListID>
        <ListID>2</ListID>
        <ListID>1</ListID>
      </ListIDS>
    </List>
  </Lists>
</SEARCH>
```

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Your sample XML *doesn't* have an `id` element in the namespace with the `nss` alias. It would be `<nss:id>` in that case, or there'd be a default namespace set up. I've assumed for this answer that in reality the element you're looking for *is* in the namespace.

Your query is trying to find an element called `id` at the root level. To find *all* `id` elements, you need:

```
var tempId = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//nss:id", ns);
```

... although personally I'd use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(...);
XNamespace nss = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner";
// Or use FirstOrDefault(), or whatever...
XElement idElement = doc.Descendants(nss + "id").Single();
```

(I prefer using the query methods on LINQ to XML types instead of XPath... I find it easier to avoid silly syntax errors etc.)

Your sample code is also unclear as you're using `xDoc` which hasn't been declared... it helps to write *complete* examples, ideally including everything required to compile and run as a console app.

Comment: its my bad..sorry about unclear code i corrected my code now.Id element in xml will be like <id> not <nss:id>. and i have tried like Content1.XPathSelectElements("//nss:id", ns) ,Content1.XPathSelectElements("//id", ns) but nothing is working :(

Comment: @mathesh: If it's not going to be in a namespace, why were you trying to use a namespace-qualified version? Either way, I'd still use the XElement/XDocument methods for finding content rather than XPath, personally.

Comment: basically there is another element which is in the namespace like <nss:name> so im trying to get id in this way.im in the situation to use XPath.Is there any to get id using XPath?

Comment: @mathesh: Quite possibly, but why would you *not* want to use the methods provided? What do you mean by "I'm in the situation to use XPath"? If you really have to use XPath (and `XPathSelectElements`), please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem, so it's easier for us to find the problem. I'd expect an XPath expression of just "//id" to work.

Comment: i have updated my sample code.can you please tell me why xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ID") and xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Lists//List/ListIDS/ListIDS") returns null.thanks

Comment: @mathesh: You still haven't provided a short but complete program. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints Note that "//" within an XPath expression probably *isn't* what you want...

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at the question 3 hours after it was submitted and 41 minutes after it was (last) edited.

There are no namespaces defined in the provided XML document.

> ```
>     var listIds = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Lists//List/ListIDS/ListIDS");
> ```

This XPath expression obviously doesn't select any node from the provided XML document, because the XML document doesn't have a top element named `Lists` (the name of the actual top element is `SEARCH`)

> ```
> var id = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ID");
> ```
>
> in load function,im getting both id and and listIds as null.

This statement is false, because `//ID` selects the only element named ID in the provided XML document, thus the value of the C# variable `id` is non-null. Probably you didn't test thoroughly after editing the XML document.

Most probably the original `ID` element belonged to some namespace. But now it is in "no namespace" and the XPath expression above does select it.

Comment: thanks.my syntax is wrong. i should give var listIds = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Lists//List/ListIDS/ListID"); instead of var listIds = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Lists//List/ListIDS/ListIDS");

Comment: @mathesh: No, *Any* XPath expression starting with `/Lists` selects zero elements when evaluated against the provided XML document. It is so simple: the Top element in the provided XML document is named `SEARCH` -- not `Lists`. You need to read any introductory book/tutorial and learn at least the very basics of XPath.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string xmldocument = "<response xmlns:nss=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner\"><action>test</action><id>1</id></response>";

        XElement Content = XElement.Parse(xmldocument);
        XPathNavigator navigator = Content.CreateNavigator();
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("nss", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner");
        var tempId = navigator.SelectSingleNode("/id");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the null value or system returned value is due to the following

```
 var id = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ID");
```

XpathSElectElements is System.xml.linq.XElment which is linq queried date. It cannot be directly outputed as such.
To Get individual first match element 
use XPathSelectElement("//ID");
You can check the number of occurrences using XPathSelectElements as

```
var count=xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ID").count();
```

you can also query the linq statement as order by using specific conditions

Inorder to get node value from a list u can use this

```
foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("//ListIDS/ListID"))
{
Console.WriteLine(xNode.InnerText);
}
```

For Second list you havnt got the value since, the XPath for list items is not correct

Comment: thanks i getting value now.i changed my code bit. i used var listIds = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Lists//List/ListIDS/ListID"); instead of var listIds = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Lists//List/ListIDS/ListIDS");