# Linq query Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 2

Tags: c#, linq

This is returning the right Element cause in the intel-sense the nexp reads 
like this  Offline  I am trying to change the Element with the Offline value to Ready.

```
public void ChangeConnectionStatus(string SelectedFile)
        { 
      System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server\server.config\DC_Classes\");
            //Getting All file names from the directory info
            System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles(SelectedFile + "*.xml*");
            //Foreach itterator
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileNames)
            {
                XElement main = XElement.Load(fi.FullName);

               IEnumerable<XElement> Nongroups = from nexp in main.XPathSelectElements("Network/Posted_Status")
                            where nexp.Element("Posted_Status").Value == "Offline"
                            select nexp;
            ////Handle the process here
            foreach (XElement nexp in Nongroups)
            {
               DialogResult Yes = MessageBox.Show("This Will Online This Group Are You Sure You Want To Do This","System Info",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
               if (Yes == DialogResult.Yes)
               {
                   nexp.SetValue("Ready");
               }
             }
          }

      }
```

Comment: Looks like "Posted_Status" element may not exist and therefore `.Value` throws. You can use explicit conversion operator instead of `.Value` like this `(string)nexp.Element("Posted_Status")`

Comment: What does your XML look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the type of the object, then just use `var`

```
foreach (var nexp in Nongroups)
```

And assign the value in this way:

```
if (Yes == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    nexp.Element("Posted_Status").Value = "Ready";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are missing the namespace as you can see in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574139/xpathselectelements-returns-null) thread. So i am expecting `nexp` is being set to null on this line:

> from **nexp** in main.XPathSelectElements("Network/Posted_Status")

You can read this [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6a8dff3-0fb8-4011-b610-554a49202e3e/xpathselectelement-always-returns-null) as well.

Give it a try, hope it helps!

Comment: I changed my code to the Inumerable<XElemement> now its says it a Null Reference

Comment: could you please make your query like this and see what happens : `IEnumerable<XElement> Nongroups = from nexp in main.XPathSelectElements("Network/Posted_Status") select nexp`